# WooCommerce variable discount based on product category and logged in user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, custom-fields

We have an e-commerce site with two categories of products that receive variable discounts based on values set in custom fields per user. One product (shirts in the example below) has one (or more) synced force sell products of another type (shoes in the example).

We need to provide a user discount which is different per category. This is working fine everywhere we want to display the user's custom discounted price, except when we add the products to the cart.

When that happens, one discount level takes over.

Example:

```css
User1
Custom Fields:
    Shirt = 44
    Shoes = 66
```

We are using this code to accomplish this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'custom_price_WPA111772', 40, 2);

//add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'custom_price_WPA111772', 99, 2);
/**
 * custom_price_WPA111772
 *
 * filter the price based on category and user role
 * @param  $price   
 * @param  $product
 * @return
 */
function custom_price_WPA111772($price, $product) {
if (!is_user_logged_in()) return $price;

//check if the product is in a category you want, let say shirts
if( has_term( array('Shirt'), 'product_cat' ,$product->ID) ) {
$shirt_level = get_field('shirt_level', 'user_'.get_current_user_id());
if($shirt_level != 0 || $shirt_level != null)
{
  $price = $price * (1 - ($shirt_level/100));
}else{
  $price = $price;
}   

}else{
$shoe_level = get_field('shoe_level', 'user_'.get_current_user_id());
if($shoe_level != 0 || $shoe_level != null)
{
  $price = $price * (1 - $shoe_level/100);
}else{
  $price = $price;
}
}

return $price;
```

When we use this example above, the shoes that are synced force sell products correctly get discounted by 66 percent. But the shirt is also discounted by 66 percent, rather than the 44 percent discount it should have.

This code does work around the site, but **fails only when the products are actually in the cart**. 
At that point, **one category discount** is applied **to all products**.

All we can come up with, is that the forced sync is somehow connecting the two categories.
Does anyone have any insight they can provide?

Comment: Just to reiterate -- this code does work around the site, but fails only when the products are actually in the cart. At that point, one category discount is applied to all products.

Comment: You can try using this plugin for category discount. I found it handy for my site. https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-product-category-discount/